# java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large bitmap

Tags: android

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:backgroundTint="#54ddde" />
```

Currently, floating button's image is android. But I want to change to 'plus' image.

-like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:fabSize="normal"
    android:src="@drawable/img_plus"
    android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    app:backgroundTint="#54ddde" />
```

However I only change image, the app has stopped. I am really embarrassed.
Can someone help me please.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(110250000bytes) bitmap.
 at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
 at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1420)
 at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
 at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1286)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18313)
 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18075)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18316)
 at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:2774)
 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18075)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17286)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18075)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17286)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18075)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17286)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18075)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17286)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18075)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17286)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18075)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
 at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
 at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18316)
 at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:850)
 at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291)
 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:666)
 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:672)
 at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:780)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3093)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2889)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2483)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1490)
 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7027)
 at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
 at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
 at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6688)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

Here is error in log cat.

Comment: post the error ..

Comment: do you have error log?

Comment: Make sure your img_plus is a png

Comment: Make sure it located in drawable folder too

Comment: img_plus is already png and  located in drawable. What seems to be a problem?

Comment: `trying to draw too large(110250000bytes) bitmap.`, resize your image to 24px X 24px and try again. Ideally you must have a valid svg image or 4 to 5 copies of png image based on the screen density.

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP didn't even try to understand the error message, which is self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was inexperienced to confirm error verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it progamatically, Try this.

```
    ImageView icon = new ImageView(this); // Create an icon
    icon.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.add_user));

    //set the appropriate background for the main floating action button along with its icon
    FloatingActionButton factionButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .setContentView(icon)
            .setBackgroundDrawable(R.drawable.selector_floating_button)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 3):

if you are using .jpg format then you can compressed that image by converting into webp format
 click[image]

Comment: Post the path to this button, not an image with it.

Comment: This makes amazing things 11MB image into 1.5MB with 0.9 quality set. Amazing answer

Comment: This is useful when you are looking to reduce the size of image in terms of memory but it may reduce considerably the quality of image so, use this if you don't care about that

Answer (score 1):

Replace all the **splash** screens with lower resolution images **JPG/PNG**, below are the resolution as required as per the devices (folder in the res/drawable) which might help, check the size and the resolution of the splash screen images you have used currently.

1. 320*480 - MDPI
2. 480*800 - HDPI
3. 720*1280 - XHDPI
4. 960*1600 - XXHDPI
5. 1280*1920 - XXXHDPI