# My App is crashing at Android Version 7.0 but why?

Tags: android, view, crash, crash-reports

In the Developer Console I get following Crash Report (only by devices with Android version 7.0):

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:260)
  at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1420)
  at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:545)
  at android.widget.ImageView.onDraw(ImageView.java:1286)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18318)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17296)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17291)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18080)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3966)
  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3752)
  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18321)
  at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:919)
  at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:17296)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:692)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:698)
  at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:806)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:3128)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2924)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2516)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1515)
  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7091)
  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:927)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:638)
  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:913)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
```

My app is working on every other Android Version less than 7.
What does this error message mean and how can I solve it?

Here is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.penta.games.mrpolitik"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:1.1.8'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:expandableheightlistview:1.0.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Maybe this line causes the crash?

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:25.2.0'
```

Comment: There is some issue on you CustomView. Can you paste the relevant code for it

Comment: Similar to yours Check if relevant : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642885/java-lang-runtimeexception-canvas-trying-to-draw-too-large-bitmap

Comment: Are u sure his error only occur in android 7? Because this kind of error only generate when android system try to draw large size bitmap

Comment: @TerrilThomas I postet the code from my ExpandableListView Adapter. This is the only code which conatins the words "ViewGroup"

Comment: But according to the crash it has something to drawing of image

Comment: @TerrilThomas I postet my build.gradle. Maybe the error is in there?

Comment: If you have this hosted on GitHub can you share the GitHub link to check the source base. I don't think Gradle dependency has anything to do with this and if you think try to remove and run it on an emulator with that version.

Comment: @TerrilThomas     1. I have an AMD processor, so my CPU is not supporting VT-x or SVM, thats why I cant test it on my Emulator. 2. GitHub is only working right if I upload the project directly after creating it. If I try to upload my current project then it is only uploading the .idea folder (Don't ask me why)

Comment: @TerrilThomas Here is the GitHub link to this project https://github.com/Penta-Games/Mr.Politik

Comment: @TheUseraccawd have you found a solution?